# Angular 2 foreach executed before array is altered by another function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm having some troubles with an array I have to alter and use again in an foreach. Here is a part of the code:

```
this.selectedDepartementen.forEach(element => {
      this.DepID = element.ID;
      if (this.USERSDepIDs.indexOf(this.DepID) == -1) {
        this.insertDepartementCoupling(this.DepID, this.USERid, this.AJID, res => {
          if (res) {
            this.loading = false;
            return;
          }
          this.removeAllFromArray(this.USERSDepIDs, this.DepID, res => {
            this.USERSDepIDs = res;
          })
        })
      } else
      {
        this.updateDepartementCoupling(this.DepID, this.USERid, this.AJID, res => {
          if (res) {
            this.loading = false;
            return;
          }
          this.removeAllFromArray(this.USERSDepIDs, this.DepID, res => {
            this.USERSDepIDs = res;
          })
        })
      }
    });
```

As you can see am I calling the function `removeAllFromArray` that removes the last used `DepID`. But the foreach doesn't wait for that function, it just keeps going. I'm guessing this is an async thing, but how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Adding function `insertDepartementCoupling` for user Duncan.

```
async insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID, callback) {
    var test = await this.departementService.insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID).subscribe(
      data => this.mockdata = data,
      error => {
        this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt, zie console voor meer informatie.");
        callback(true);
      },
      () => {
        if (this.mockdata._body) {
          this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Contacteer de administrator!");
          callback(true);
        } else {
          this.showMessage("succes", "Departement koppeling geslaagd!", "Gebruiker is gekoppeld aan de departement(en).");
          callback(false);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the other functions you are using? They are using callbacks and that will make it very difficult to ensure that everything happens in a sensible order. If you can modify them to return promises instead the code should become much simpler as then you can use async/await to flatten the code.

Comment: I can rewrite everything. Can you give me a small example how I can use async/await to flatten code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `insertDepartmentCoupling` and `updateDepartementCoupling` so that instead of a callback they return a promise which resolves with the result that would have been passed to the callback, and you also do the same for `removeAllFromArray` (does that one need to be asynchronous at all?), then make the function which contains the code you posted `async`, then you could use something like this code:

```
for (const element of this.selectedDepartementen) {
    this.DepID = element.ID;
    if (this.USERSDepIDs.indexOf(this.DepID) == -1) {
        if (await this.insertDepartementCoupling(this.DepID, this.USERid, this.AJID)) {
            this.loading = false;
        } else {
            this.USERSDepIDs = await this.removeAllFromArray(this.USERSDepIDs, this.DepID);
        }
    } else {
        if (await this.updateDepartementCoupling(this.DepID, this.USERid, this.AJID)) {
            this.loading = false;
        } else {
            this.USERSDepIDs = await this.removeAllFromArray(this.USERSDepIDs, this.DepID);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with typescript you can use `for..of` to iterate an array rather than `forEach` and avoid another callback.

This code is now clear in how it executes, and in particular the `for` loop will do one iteration at a time waiting for everything to complete, but it is still fully asynchronous. The function that contains it must be declared with the `async` keyword and must itself return a `Promise` which you can either `await` or handle via a `.then()` callback.

Your `insertDepartementCoupling` function is already async, and uses an observer internally, so the easiest way to remove the callback and return a promise instead is just to use `toPromise()` on the observable. That promise will complete with the last data value but you can use `.then()` to get the boolean value you want to return:

```
async insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID): Promise<boolean> {
    let result = false;
    var test = await this.departementService.insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID).subscribe(
      data => this.mockdata = data,
      error => {
        this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt, zie console voor meer informatie.");
        result = true;
      },
      () => {
        if (this.mockdata._body) {
          this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Contacteer de administrator!");
          result = true;
        } else {
          this.showMessage("succes", "Departement koppeling geslaagd!", "Gebruiker is gekoppeld aan de departement(en).");
          result = false;
        }
      }).toPromise();
     return result;
  }
```

Alternatively you could convert the `Observable` to a promise sooner and then you don't need the intermediate variable:

```
async insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.departementService.insertDepartementCoupling(DepID, USERid, AJID).toPromise()
    .then(
      data => {
        this.mockdata = data
        if (this.mockdata._body) {
          this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Contacteer de administrator!");
          return true;
        } else {
          this.showMessage("succes", "Departement koppeling geslaagd!", "Gebruiker is gekoppeld aan de departement(en).");
          return false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.showMessage("error", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt!", "Departement koppeling niet gelukt, zie console voor meer informatie.");
        return true;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! The returned promise should just contain true or false, I can't find how I can create this? I'll add the function `insertDepartmentCoupling` so you can see what's going on there

Comment: You're amazing!! I can use this on all my callback functions! Thank you so much!